# Selenium how to get the alert Alert message

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi i am using the below  for retrieving the alert message data  but it is failed

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String ss1=alert.getText();
```

it display the bellow  error message .

```
Popup present/Not : true
FAILED: Login
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is present (WARNING: The server
       did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.25 seconds
Build info: version: '2.23.0', revision: '17137', time: '2012-06-07 15:43:04'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', 
java.version:     '1.7.0_17'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Session ID: 0c684096-46e6-4f00-8434-af866eb29746
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:458)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:462)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.alert(RemoteWebDriver.java:733)
at popupI_datachecking.Login(popupI_datachecking.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Comment: Cannot help much with little information provided, but, if you are trying to get any element in your selenium script when alert is shown, then your alert will disappear and you get this error.

Answer (score 5):

Based upon this in your stacktrace:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is present (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Selenium doesn't think that a popup is present, you may want to wait for it to appear:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100)
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
```

The above code snippet will make selenium wait for up to 15 seconds for the alert to appear checking every 100 ms to see if it has appeared.

Comment: where exactly do you put this snippet? after you initialize Alert alert or before?

Comment: You'll need to trigger the alert before you wait for it to appear.