# How to close a pop up window in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to close a pop up window which is not allowing my code to execute further. But I am unable to do that. There is a a pop up window which says 'Free pound 5 voucher' which is not getting closed.

Below is my code. Please check and suggest.

```
public class Alldetails {
    WebDriver driver;
    public List<String> links1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Pankaj\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void f() {
        driver.get("http://www.debenhams.com/kids/t-shirts-tops/boys");
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath(".//*[@id='dijit__WidgetsInTemplateMixin_0']/div/div[1]/button"))
                .click();

        WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.className("products_count"));
        String product_count = a.getText();
        Integer x = Integer.valueOf(product_count);
        System.out.println(x);
        for (int i = 1; i < (x / 60) + 1; i++) {
            driver.get("http://www.debenhams.com/kids/t-shirts-tops/boys" + "?pn=" + i);

            List<WebElement> links = driver
                    .findElements(By.className("item_container").tagName("a"));
            for (WebElement abcx : links) {
                String ax = abcx.getAttribute("href");
                // if(!links1.contains(ax))
                links1.add(ax);
            }

            for (String b : links1) {
                if (b.contains("/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/prod"))
                    System.out.println(b);
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
    }
}
```

Comment: In this code on which action that pop up appears? or when that pop up appears? please more ellaborate?

Comment: The pop up appears after the below line of code.                                                                            'driver.get("http://www.debenhams.com/kids/t-shirts-tops/boys"+"?pn="+i);
'

Comment: What kind of popup? JavaScript alert? HTML/CSS popup? Browser popup?

Comment: Seems like its a javascript pop up. It appears on the page http://www.debenhams.com/kids/t-shirts-tops/boys?pn=1

Comment: It is not an Browser Alert box, it is a html popup advert created by html injection by an adserver.  Deal with it exactly the same way as you would with any interactive element.  Fluent wait for it to appear then, click "//a[@class='modalCloseImg simplemodal-close']" element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
// Prints text and closes alert
System.out.println(alert.getText());
alert.accept();
```

or

```
alert.dismiss();
```

according to your needs.

**EDIT**

You may get an AlertNotPresentException if your code runs before the alert appears. In order to avoid that you may add a delay like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
```

This will make Selenium wait 15 seconds checking every 100 milliseconds if the alert appeared. This snippet is not mine and had been taken from here: [Selenium how to get the alert Alert message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273261/selenium-how-to-get-the-alert-alert-message)

Comment: The error message is not appearing now but the URLs that should be printing after this is not there. I coded this to fetch all the product URLs on this page.

Comment: The error what It is throwing the exception org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open

Comment: I am getting timeout exception now.                                                                         FAILED: f
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 15 seconds waiting for alert to be present

Comment: It seems that Selenium isn't able to find the alert. If I were you I'd try to wrap your code with a try-catch for an UnhandledAlertException and only in that case doing switchTo().alert() and alert.dismiss()

Comment: Because it is not an browser alert, it is html injection code for pop up. YOu don't need to use Alert class. Simple use the locators to access the elements on html popup.